# How to config mypy to recognize imports?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import, mypy

I am trying to configure a MAKEFILE that runs mypy on my project.

I have configured mypy to use:
`explicit_package_bases = true` and I am able to run the mypy tests without complaints of import errors. But when I import any object in the code, mypy does not recognize its types and it assumes that all the typing is Any. I am seeing errors similar to this one:
`Returning Any from function declared to return "List[Any]"  [no-any-return]`
The function in question DOES have explicit typing.

The structure of my directory looks like this:

```
app
├── source 
│   ├── project 
│   │   ├── foo
|   |   |   ├──__init__.py
|   |   |   ├──foo_file1.py
|   |   |   └──foo_file2.py
│   │   └── bar
|   |   |   ├──__init__.py
|   |   |   ├──bar_file1.py
|   |   |   └──bar_file2.pypy
│   └── pyproject.toml
└── MAKEFILE
```

An import from foo_file1.py might look like:
`from project.bar.bar_file1 import function1`

The command for running mypy in the MAKEFILE looks like this:
`mypy source --config-file source/pyproject.toml`

The mypy config within my pyproject.toml file looks like:

```
[tool.mypy]
strict = true
show_error_codes = true
explicit_package_bases = true
```

When I change the import from
`from project.bar.bar_file1 import function1` to `from ..bar.bar_file1 import function1` all of the mypy errors that I expect are highlighted. I want to find a way to make this work without having to change all my imports.

The root directory of `project` does not contain an `__init__.py` file because of a name conflict with another package that we import in the code. I would rather not create an init file at this time. And renaming the whole directory is a huge pain because of a pre-existing deployment process and other people working on branches for this code. I am trying to do this without being intrusive to other people that use this codebase.